# How to create function based on this requirement?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, oracle11g, package

HOW TO EXECUTE PACKAGED FUNCTION IN ANONYMOUS BLOCK?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name(n_fdo number, n_perc varchar2,
n_rating varchar2,
n_oto varchar2,
n_rate varchar2,
n_vlore varchar2,
n_prdotto varchar2,
n_scrd varchar2,
n_retail varchar2,
n_porto varchar2)Return NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's function's description. It accepts number of parameters, **all of them** are obligatory (as they don't have default value).

As you want to all it from anonymous PL/SQL block, you'd declare a variable whose datatype matches the one returned by that function (it is `NUMBER`), pass parameters and - that's it.

```
declare
  result number;
begin
  result := function_name(n_fdo   => 1,
                          n_perc  => 'ABC',
                          ...
                          n_porto => 'XYZ');
end;
/
```

Comment: Just as a remark: If it is a "PACKAGED" function then the name of the package should precede the function name: -->    result := package_name.function_name(parameters)

Comment: Certainly, @dr. According to **code** posted, it is just a *stored* function. **Text** says different. Kabilan never responded so - who knows? Thank you for the comment!